# C order of function declarations

Tags: c, function, prototype, declaration

Here is some sample code that will resemble an issue I am having

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int cube_then_square(int x){
        x = cube(x);
        return x*x;
    }

    int cube(int y){
        return y*y*y;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        printf("5 cubed then squared is: %d\n", cube_then_square(5));
        return 0;
    }
```

So the compiler gives me an issue with `cube` being undeclared. So can somebody please explain the order in which these functions are put in memory, etc...and how it would be different from putting the prototypes on top and the implementations after `main`.

Comment: It's not about the order the functions are placed in memory (which is mostly up to the linker). It's about a single-pass compiler seeing a declaration for a function before a call to that function. C++ breaks the "single pass" assumption to some degree, but only to some degree.

Comment: @chris no they don't need to be, it was forward declared when it was called (if this is C)

Comment: @SteveCox, Yes, I was talking in the context of C++. Seeing as how the tag got removed, so is my comment.

Comment: This program is legal C and compiles fine in gcc.

Comment: This will generally compile fine in a new version of GCC or clang that can do 2 pass compilation or lookahead, but it isn't required to without a prototype...

Comment: @JerryCoffin I made the edit based on the title and the fact that this looks like C code. I was not aware of this issue. OP please clarify. It does indeed compile in C11 with gcc4.9.

Comment: This is indeed C. Compiled with gcc, and the compiler did throw a "warning" not an "error." In any case, i am trying to understand the details as to why this would even be a warning. I thought all the function names got registered in memory before main started

Comment: was the warning for an implicitly declared function?

Comment: @SteveCox thats the one

Comment: You cannot call a function without declaring it in C99 (it is valid in C89), a gcc warning can very well indicate invalid code. @GradyPlayer: Modern compilers don't scan twice in such a case, gcc and clang take the call as an implicit declaration of a function returning `int` and getting a fix number of default-promoted arguments, without checking number or types of arguments, omitting a warning to indicate that this code is invalid.

Comment: @mafso you are right, I guess they added that only for Objective-C methods... I thought it was a general behavior.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: This had nothing to do with any new capabilities of modern compilers ("two pass" or not). The code is illegal in C99 and later. But if some C compiler accepts this code, it does it as an extension. And while doing that it follows the legacy rules of the original C language, i.e. it deduces the function signature from the call. No need for any extra passes.

Comment: @AndreyT I wasn't implying that it was strictly legal C Code, but I was confused, because clang does, as an extension, not require method prototypes within a single Objective-C compilation unit, for private methods et al

Answer (score 4):

The warning of an implicitly declared function exists because most modern C programs don't use implicit functions.

Old C89 allowed for implicitly declared everything. When you call a function it gets implicitly declared as `int func ()`.
This works in this situation because you implicitly declare the function `int cube()` with the line:

```
x = cube(x);
```

and then later you define the function `int cube(int)`. `int cube()` and `int cube(int)` have compatible types so this is a fine call to make.

The trouble you can really run into is calling an incompatible function from an implicitly declared function (this is really why the warning exists). `int cube(float)` is an incompatible function type that could definitely exist and if you called it with an implicitly declared function you could probably expect some pretty strange effects (read undefined). As mafso mentioned strict C99 no longer allows implicitly declared functions which is why many compilers include the warning regardless.

Remember implicitly declared function are BAD PRACTICE but you should know the exist for scenarios like this.

Here's a little program to demonstrate the weakness of implicitly declared functions. It takes advantage of some of the conversion rules you would expect in a c program that suddenly go away with implicitly declared functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

cube1(int x){return x*x*x;}
main(){float y = 9.; printf("%d\n%d\n", cube1(y), cube2(y));}
cube2(int x){return x*x*x;}
```

output:

```
729
1
```

These functions are identical in the asm

```
00000000004004dc <cube1>:
  4004dc:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004dd:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004e0:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  4004e3:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  4004e6:   0f af 45 fc             imul   -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  4004ea:   0f af 45 fc             imul   -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  4004ee:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004ef:   c3                      retq   
0000000000400540 <cube2>:
  400540:   55                      push   %rbp
  400541:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400544:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  400547:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  40054a:   0f af 45 fc             imul   -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  40054e:   0f af 45 fc             imul   -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  400552:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400553:   c3                      retq
```

But at the callsite the expected conversion from float to integer is never performed for the implicit call.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler reads the file from top to bottom. When it reaches function, it checks whether it already knows it. In this case it hasn't seen the function `cube(int)`, so it returns an error.

You can do two things: 
1. You move the function `cube` before the function `cube_then_square`.
2. You create a forward declaration before `cube_then_square`:

```
int cube(int y);
```

Answer (score 1):

To the top of your file, under the includes, add `int cube(int y);`

You have to declare a function before you use it.  It doesn't have to be defined yet, but it has to be declared before it is used, because the compiler checks lines in sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you can declare `cube` before using it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cube(int y){
    return y*y*y;
}

int cube_then_square(int x){
    x = cube(x);
    return x*x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("5 cubed then squared is: %d\n", cube_then_square(5));
    return 0;
}
```

You can also add the function header `int cube(int y);` at the top:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cube(int y);

int cube_then_square(int x){
    x = cube(x);
    return x*x;
}

int cube(int y){
    return y*y*y;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("5 cubed then squared is: %d\n", cube_then_square(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solves problem, check.
Forgot problem was example, check.
Doesn't address question, check. 
Just adding some humor, remember not to go too fast!

Answer (score 0):

It is completely irrelevant how these functions are "put in memory". In fact, this is in no way exposed at the language level. It does not matter.

When you are organizing an implementation file, you have a choice of doing it in either top-down fashion or bottom-up fashion.

In the former case upper-level functions are defined first. Upper-level functions call lower-level functions, which are defined later in the file. In order for that to work properly, the low-level functions have to be additionally prototyped before the point of the first call (e.g. at the very top of the file). (Formally, a prototype is not required, but at least a *declaration* is required.)

In the latter case lower-level functions are defined first and upper-level functions are defined later. In this approach the definitions themselves already serve as prototypes, meaning that no additional prototyping is required (unless you have a circular call dependency between functions).

Top-down is a higher maintenance approach, since you have to keep function prototypes in sync with their definitions.

What you have in your example looks like a mix of these two approaches. `main` (the highest-level function) is defined at the bottom, yet `cube_then_square` is defined before `cube`. There's nothing really wrong with that, but to keep this ordering you have to provide a prototype for `cube` at the beginning of the file.

I personally prefer the bottom-up approach. E.g. in your specific example I'd move the entire definition of `cube` to the top of the file. That would eliminate the need to provide an additional prototype.

In any case, regardless of how you do it, there's no meaningful difference in the generated code. The ordering of functions in the object file might be affected by their ordering in the source file, but this is completely inconsequential from the language point of view.